# Treetop boolean logic operations

Tags: ruby, treetop

I am implementing DSL which has syntax:

```
"[keyword] or ([other keyword] and not [one more keyword])"
```

Each keyword will transform to boolean (`true`, `false`) value and after that it should be calculated using operators  `and, or, not`

My current grammar rules match only strings `[keyword] or [other keyword]` and fails on stings `[keyword] or [other keyword] or [one more keyword]`

How to write grammar that match any ammount of `or` , `and` constructions?

Grammar:

```
grammar Sexp

  rule expression
    keyword operand keyword <ExpressionLiteral>
  end

  rule operand
   or / and <OperandLiteral>
  end

  rule or
    'or' <OrLiteral>
  end

  rule and
    'and' <AndLiteral>
  end

  rule keyword
    space '[' ( '\[' / !']' . )* ']' space <KeywordLiteral>
  end

 rule space
   ' '*
 end
end
```

**Updates**

Parser class

```
class Parser
  require 'treetop'
  base_path = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  require File.join(base_path, 'node_extensions.rb')
  Treetop.load(File.join(base_path, 'sexp_parser.treetop'))

  def  self.parse(data)
    if data.respond_to? :read
      data = data.read
    end

    parser =SexpParser.new
    ast = parser.parse data

    if ast
      #self.clean_tree(ast)
      return ast
    else
      parser.failure_reason =~ /^(Expected .+) after/m
      puts "#{$1.gsub("\n", '$NEWLINE')}:"
      puts data.lines.to_a[parser.failure_line - 1]
      puts "#{'~' * (parser.failure_column - 1)}^"
    end
  end
    private
    def self.clean_tree(root_node)
       return if(root_node.elements.nil?)
       root_node.elements.delete_if{|node| node.class.name == "Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode" }
       root_node.elements.each {|node| self.clean_tree(node) }
    end
end

tree = Parser.parse('[keyword] or [other keyword] or [this]')
p tree
p tree.to_array
```

node extension

```
module Sexp
  class KeywordLiteral < Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode
    def to_array
      self.text_value.gsub(/[\s\[\]]+/, '')
    end
  end

  class OrLiteral < Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode
    def to_array
      self.text_value
    end
  end

  class AndLiteral < Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode
    def to_array
      self.text_value
    end
  end

  class OperandLiteral < Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode
    def to_array
      self.elements.map{|e| e.to_array}
    end
  end

  class ExpressionLiteral < Treetop::Runtime::SyntaxNode
    def to_array
      self.elements.map{|e| e.to_array}.join(' ')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: My Treetop is rusty, but how about something like `rule expression; keyword / expression operand expression; end`? Or expressed via repetition instead of recursion: `rule expression; keyword (operand keyword)*; end`

Comment: @JörgWMittag not working. Treetop expect space at `operator`'s  position in both examples

Comment: You don't define whether you expect AND or OR to have greater precedence. It's common usage in computer languages that AND has higher precedence than OR, but you need to decide one way or the other or your grammar will always need parentheses. If you answer this, I can offer an answer to your question.

Comment: @cliffordheath I want to have the same behavior as ruby language has when it interpret something like this  `and false and (true or false)
#=> false`

Answer (score 4):

Ok, thanks for that clarification. In Ruby, "false and true or true" is true, because the "and" is evaluated first (it has higher precedence). To parse this, you need one rule for the "or" list (the disjunctions) which calls another rule for the "and" list (the conjunctions). Like this:

```
rule expression
  s disjunction s
  { def value; disjunction.value; end }
end

rule disjunction
  conjunction tail:(or s conjunction s)*
  { def value
      tail.elements.inject(conjunction.value) do |r, e|
        r or e.conjunction.value
      end
    end
  }
end

rule conjunction
  primitive tail:(and s primitive s)*
  { def value
      tail.elements.inject(primitive.value) do |r, e|
        r and e.primitive.value
      end
    end
  }
end

rule primitive
  '(' expression ')' s { def value; expression.value; end }
  /
  not expression  s { def value; not expression.value; end }
  /
  symbol s { def value; symbol.value; end }
end

rule or
  'or' !symbolchar s
end

rule and
  'and' !symbolchar s
end

rule not
  'not' !symbolchar s
end

rule symbol
  text:([[:alpha:]_] symbolchar*) s
  { def value
      lookup_value(text.text_value)
    end
  }
end

rule symbolchar
  [[:alnum:]_]
end

rule s # Optional space
  S?
end

rule S # Mandatory space
  [ \t\n\r]*
end
```

Note some things:

- keywords must not be immediately followed by a symbol character. I use negative lookahead for this.
- The top rule consumes leading whitespace, then almost every rule consumes following whitespace (this is my policy). You should test your grammar with minimum and maximum whitespace.
- There's no need to use a syntaxnode class on every rule, as you did.
- You can see how to continue the pattern for addition, multiplication, etc
- I've given a sketch of some code that evaluates the expression. Use something prettier please!

Comment: "false or true and true" is true

Comment: Gah! Quite right. I'll edit my description. The code is still correct.